# UITableView setEditing method causes crash due to index out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

so I have a problem with UITableView. I have self-sizing cells and one can actually change height as the `UITextView` inside changes. When I set the `UITableViewController` editing, I get an index out of bounds crash by the `super`.

The crash occurs on this line:

```
super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
```

Error I get is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 7 beyond bounds for empty array'

This out of bounds crash is not caused by a line of code that I wrote since I checked every instance where I access an array and none of them are being called when the crash occurs. The exception breakpoint points to the above line too so I am convinced this has something to do with the default `UITableViewController` implementation of `setEditing: animated:`.

An interesting point is that this error only occurs when the resizable cell is in the table view. When I create the table view without it, there are no issues. There are also no issues if I keep the cell in but don't touch any of the constraints so that it doesn't change its height. This leads me to believe that somehow a cell that changes height "in real-time" causes this strange crash but since I can't see into `UITableViewController` implementation to find the line that causes a bug, I don't know how to handle this problem.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Turns out that a more precise cause for the crash is when a cell tries to change its height as a direct result of a change in editing. So for example, a cell that simply grows or shrinks due to a text view with `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` shouldn't cause any problems. But expanding a cell when starting editing is when this issue arises.

Comment: Look at the stack trace and set an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Hi Paul, It doesn't tell me much because the calls are `[UITableViewController setEditing:animated:]`, `[UITableView _setEditing:animated:forced:]`, `[ __NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]`

Comment: Have you overridden `setEditing`?  If not, why are you calling `super.setEditing` and not `self.setEditing` ?

Comment: Yes I have overriden setEditing

Comment: In that case the issue most likely lies in your code when overriding setEditing. Please edit in more of that.

Comment: However, it doesn't seem to matter anyways because if I comment out that setEditing override, the crash simply moves to my call for controller.setEditing(true, animated: true)

Comment: Hi Dopapp, in my setEditing override I actually now only had some print statements, I used to send a notification there which is why I have the override but now I can absolutely do without it. The issue is still there though, as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: hey @DenisBalko do you remember how did you solve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I did not, just had to find an alternate approach to the whole thing